java.net.SocketTimeoutException retrofit
We are using a Retrofit 2.6 client to call a partner server, but for some calls, we are getting a socket connection timeout exception. We also have a Step Functions activity poller implemented within an ECS service, which executes the activity in a new thread, and the activity's work is to call a partner API. We are only getting this exception in the case of calls made via Step Function activities. It only fails for some calls.
Exception:
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java: 350)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java: 206)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java: 188)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java: 392)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java: 607)
at okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform.connectSocket(Platform.java: 129)
at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.java: 247)
at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java: 167)
at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java: 258)
at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java: 135)
at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java: 114)
at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java: 42)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java: 147)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java: 121)
at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java: 93)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java: 147)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java: 121)
at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java: 93)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java: 147)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java: 126)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java: 147)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java: 121)
at configuration.utils.RetrofitClientHelper.lambda$addResponseInterceptor$1(RetrofitClientHelper.java: 84)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java: 147)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java: 121)
at configuration.utils.RetrofitClientHelper.lambda$addRequestInterceptor$0(RetrofitClientHelper.java: 75)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java: 147)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java: 121)
at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java: 250)
at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java: 93)
at retrofit2.OkHttpCall.execute(OkHttpCall.java: 188)
at RetrofitWrapper.execute(RetrofitWrapper.java: 29)
    ...11 more

We anticipated that the [Retrofit connection pool was getting timed out, so we implemented this change because of known java.net.SocketTimeoutException from HTTP/2 connection leaves dead okhttp clients in pool](https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/3146) issue.
OkHttpClient.Builder okHttpClientBuilder = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
.retryOnConnectionFailure(false)
.connectionPool(new ConnectionPool(MAX_IDLE_CONNECTION, KEEP_ALIVE_DURATION, TimeUnit.MINUTES)) // added this
.protocols(Collections.singletonList(Protocol.HTTP_1_1)) // added this
.readTimeout(CommonConstants.READ_WRITE_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
.writeTimeout(CommonConstants.READ_WRITE_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
.connectTimeout(CommonConstants.DEFAULT_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

MAX_IDLE_CONNECTION = 0, KEEP_ALIVE_DURATION = 5
but we are still seeing this exception. It only fails for some calls.
